Pretty-print indices/coordinates of 2D Numpy array
Does Numpy provide built-in capabilities to print the indices/coordinates of a 2-d Numpy array at its borders?
What I mean is the following: Given, for example, the array
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3).astype(float)

I would like to have a printout as follows:
     0    1    2
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  3.0  4.0  5.0

It needn't be exactly like that, but the corresponding information should be conveyed. That is, I want to have a "header column" that shows the row indices (here: 0, 1) and a "header row" that shows the column indices (here: 0, 1, 2).
At present, I simply use Pandas for this purpose (i.e. I convert the Numpy array to a Pandas DataFrame and then print the DataFrame). This is also suggested, for example, in this answer to a related question. However, this would always require Pandas, even if I don't use it for anything else in a given project.
So my question, again, is: can I achieve the same printout only with Numpy (thus without Pandas)? Or, if not, is there a lightweight solution (in the sense of a few lines of code without an additional library) to achieve a similar output?

No, I'm not aware of any built-in functionality in NumPy to print arrays in this format. I was about to write an answer showing how to do it via Pandas, and then saw your second paragraph.

@jakevdp Thanks a lot for your input, in any case! I guess, "no" sometimes is just the appropriate answer.

You can try:
import numpy as np

def pretty_print(arr, precision=2, sep=1):
    # Convert array contents to list of list of formatted strings
    rows = [[f"{v:.{precision}f}" for v in row] for row in arr]
    # Calculate width of row index's column (maxl) and remaining columns (maxw)
    maxl = len(str(arr.shape[0] - 1))
    maxw = max(len(str(arr.shape[1] - 1)), *(len(v) for row in rows for v in row))
    # Print column indexes and content, pad string entries to appropriate width
    print(" " * maxl, *(f"{i:>{maxw}}" for i in range(0, arr.shape[1])), sep=" " * sep)
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        print(f"{i:>{maxl}}", *(f"{v:>{maxw}}" for v in row), sep=" " * sep)

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4).astype(float)
a[0, 0] = np.inf
a[1, 1] = -np.inf
a[2, 3] *= -1
pretty_print(a, precision=2, sep=1)
pretty_print(np.ones(shape=(3, 14)), precision=0)

Prints:
       0      1      2      3
0    inf   1.00   2.00   3.00
1   4.00   -inf   6.00   7.00
2   8.00   9.00  10.00 -11.00

and
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1


That's basically exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

I just discovered a subtle bug: Take pretty_print(np.ones(shape=(14, 14)), precision=0): Here, the index values are wider than the widest array value, but they are currently not taken into account when calculating maxw. A simple fix is replacing maxw = max(len(v) for row in rows for v in row) with maxw = max(len(str(arr.shape[1])), *(len(v) for row in rows for v in row)).

Fixed another edge case: maxl = len(str(arr.shape[0])) should be maxl = len(str(arr.shape[0] - 1)), same for maxw. Take an array with 10 rows, for example: as Python indexes are 0-based, its largest index is 9, so still a 1-digit number, while maxl = len(str(arr.shape[0])) would imply that we already need to reserve space for a 2-digit number in the index column.
